# NestJS - Return ACK in exception filter

Tags: node.js, websocket, nestjs

I have the following example:

```
@SubscribeMessage('v1-test')
@UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
@UseFilters(ValidationOnSocketExceptionFilter)
async test(
  @MessageBody() payload: payloadDTO,
  @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket,
){
   .....do stuff......
   return true;
}
```

And here is the ValidationOnSocketExceptionFilter:

```
 @Catch(BadRequestException)
export class ValidationOnSocketExceptionFilter
  implements ExceptionFilter<BadRequestException> {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(ValidationOnSocketExceptionFilter.name);

  constructor(private readonly customResponseService: CustomResponseService) {}

  catch(exception: BadRequestException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    console.log('Validation err on socket');

    const client = host.switchToWs().getClient();

    // * get the msg from all validation erros
    let constraints: string[] | string;

    if (typeof exception.getResponse() === 'object') {
      let err: any = exception.getResponse();
      if (err.message && Array.isArray(err.message)) constraints = err.message;
    } else {
      constraints = exception.getResponse() as string;
    }

    const err: CustomResponse = this.customResponseService.buildErrorResponse(
      ErrCodes.BAD_PARAMETERS,
      constraints,
    );

    console.log(client);
    client.emit(SocketMessages.CustomError, err);
  }
}
```

What I want to do is not create and send a new event using **client.emit(SocketMessages.CustomError, err);**, but rather to simple use **return err**, meaning that I want to return the error using the acknowledgement function, same I'm doing inside the function **test()**

Answer (score 7):

You can get callback function through 3rd argument in `ArgumentsHost`.

```js
catch(exception: BadRequestException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
  // ...

  const err: CustomResponse = this.customResponseService.buildErrorResponse(
    ErrCodes.BAD_PARAMETERS,
    constraints,
  );

  const callback = host.getArgByIndex(2);
  if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback(err);
  }
}
```

Tested only with `@nestjs/platform-socket.io`.

Comment: This works for me. When I throw a WsException in my guard, it is sent as a separate message called "exception". However, when I call the callback as suggested in this answer, it is send as the ACK. I would have expected the exception to be sent as the ACK in the context of socket.io. Is this possible?

Comment: Just saw the implementation here: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/websockets/exceptions/base-ws-exception-filter.ts - it's calling emit. So, to get an ACK on WsException, I have just created SioException extends WsException, and then created an ExceptionFilter for SioException that responds using the 3rd arg callback instead of emit.